# How is searching not like seeking and vice versa?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What makes searching not like seeking?
What makes seeking not like searching?

How do we decide when to use one over the other?

Comment: If you search a crime scene for evidence you're not necessarily seeking any particular thing.  Note that the two verbs take different objects -- "search" takes the area being examined and "seek" takes the item being sought.

Comment: What @HotLicks said,  A search radar is not seeking a particular threat but rather shows whatever is out there.

Answer (score -1):

The designation of seek/search is dependent on the imperative of verb. To seek something implies a definite end result. It is essentially a request. To search implies an ambiguous end result. It is more passive, and observational. One can search for evidence in a crime scene, but to seek evidence would be improper and imply prior knowledge of the sought evidence (and the nature therein).